# Hiding the RecognizerUI in Windows Phone 8 Apps

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to hide the RecognizerUI when using the Windows Phone 8 voice recognition?

Basically, I want enable my app to start listening but to have the current page of my app still displayed. I would like my app to be listening all the time without the pop up.

Is this at all possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In doing a little more research it looks like [RadControls for Windows Phone 8](http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone.aspx) is the only set of controls that do what I want. This will allow you to enable voice commands through the xaml rather than the code behind. I tried this out and sure enough it works great!

The article that helped me out is here: http://blogs.telerik.com/michaelcrump/posts/12-11-19/speech-recognition-made-easy-with-telerik-radcontrols-for-wp8.aspx